# Save one line of `top`, `htop` or `intel_gpu_top` outputs into a Bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I want to save 1 line from the output of `top` into a Bash array to later access its components:

```
$ timeout 1 top -d 2 | awk 'NR==8'
   2436 USER       20   0 1040580 155268  91100 S   6.2   1.0  56:38.94 Xorg
Terminated
```

I tried:

```
$ gpu=($(timeout 1s top -d 2 | awk 'NR==8'))
$ mapfile -t gpu < <($(timeout 1s top -d 2 | awk 'NR==8'))
```

and, departing from the array requisite, even:

```
$ read -r gpu < <(timeout 1s top -d 2 | awk 'NR==8')
```

all returned a blank for either `${gpu[@]}` (first two) or `$gpu` (last).

**Edit:**
As pointed out by @Cyrus and others `gpu=($(top -n 1 -d 2 | awk 'NR==8'))` is the obvious solution. However I want to build the cmd dynamically so `top -d 2`  may be replaced by other cmds such as `htop -d 20` or `intel_gpu_top -s 1`. Only `top` can limit its maximum number of iterations, so that is not an option in general, and for that reason I resort to `timeout 1s` to kill the process in all shown attempts... 
**End edit**

Using a shell other than Bash is **not** an option. Why did the above attempts fail and how can I achieve that ?

Comment: `gpu=($(top -n 1 -d 2 | awk 'NR==8'))`?

Comment: this whole line of work seems a bit iffy (to me) ... between different top implementations, default start up settings, settings loaded from a personal (.)toprc, and the potential for a lot of control characters in the output; the `NR==8` seems to imply some expectation that line 8 is ... what ... the top (2nd? 3rd?) process currently eating up the most cpu (or memory? or ... would depend on what the `top` output is sorted by); I'm wondering if it might make more sense to describe what you're trying to capture and then see if there's a more direct way of obtaining said info ... ???

Comment: assuming the objective is to capture a process that's currently 1st in terms of cpu (or memory, or ....), I'm wondering if things would be simpler with `top -n 1 -b` (run in `-b`atch mode => textual output w/out all of the control chraracters); some (relatively) simple `awk`ing could be used to parse the data to find the desired pid; once the data's found then the current methods for loading into a bash array should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did the above attempts fail

Because redirection to pipe does not have [terminal capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html), `top` process receives `SIGTTOU` signal when it tries to write the terminal and take the terminal "back" from the shell. The signal causes `top` to terminate.

> how can I achieve that ?

Use `top -n 1`. Generally, use the tool specific options to disable using terminal utilities by that tool.

> However I want to build the cmd dynamically so top -d 2 may be replaced by other cmds such as htop -d 20 or intel_gpu_top -s 1

Write your own terminal emulation and extract the first line from the buffer of the first stuff the command displays. See GNU `screen` and `tmux` source code for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need the timeout there if its intended to quit top. You can instead use the -n and -b flags but feel free to add it if you need it

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=()
arr[0]=$(top -n 1 -b -d 2 | awk 'NR==8')
arr[1]=random-value
arr[2]=$(top -n 1 -b -d 2 |awk 'NR==8')
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[1]}
echo ${arr[2]}

output:
    1 root 20 0 99868 10412 7980 S 0.0 0.5 0:00.99 systemd
    random-value
    1 root 20 0 99868 10412 7980 S 0.0 0.5 0:00.99 systemd
```

from top man page:

```
 -b  :Batch-mode operation
            Starts top in Batch mode, which could be useful for sending output from top to other  programs  or  to  a
            file.   In  this  mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with the
            `-n' command-line option or until killed.
 -n  :Number-of-iterations limit as:  -n number
        Specifies the maximum number of iterations, or frames, top should produce before ending.
 -d  :Delay-time interval as:  -d ss.t (secs.tenths)
            Specifies the delay between screen updates, and overrides  the  corresponding  value  in  one's  personal
            configuration  file  or  the  startup default.  Later this can be changed with the `d' or `s' interactive
            commands.
```